# Show the module of continuous functions of antiperiod $\pi$ is not cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Homework Hint Needed:

Let $R$ be the ring of all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ of period $\pi$. Let $S$ be the $R$-module of all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ of antiperiod $\pi$. So elements of $S$ satisfy $$f(x + \pi) = -f(x).$$

How can I show that this module is not cyclic?

It seems that it has something to do with not being able to write both sine and cosine as multiples of a single antiperiodic function $p(x)$. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $p$ is a continuous antiperiodic function that is cyclic. Note any multiple of $p$ must be zero wherever $p$ is zero. Since there exist anti periodic functions with disjoint zero sets (e.g. sine and cosine), what must be true about the zero set of $p$? Does there exist such a $p$?

Comment: Ah, yes. I see. This will force $p$ to be always positive or always negative, which would make $p$ not antiperiodic.

Comment: Right! Where "This" = "The fact that $p$ cannot have any zeros".